# how to get content of css selector using php simple dom parser?

Tags: php, html, css-selectors, simple-html-dom

[image: Image Link]

here content in blue from image i need to parse i.e £29 - £117
am using this to get content

```
$price=$con->find('div.event-availability p',0)->innertext;
echo"price";
```

as CSS selector (`::before`) is present here unable to parse this content.
need output as '£29 - £117'

how to get this output?
any other method?

Comment: Can you post URL of the page of the real HTML? The source in Inspector can be different from original source.

Comment: hi, I've checked the page that you're trying to scrape and it isn't going to work with PHP simple dom. Why? Well right click on the page and look at the source code. Can you find the price there? Nope. You need to find yourself another type of parser, I'm not sure which one though.

Answer (score 0):

The `::before` won't even be detected by the parser as that gets applied after the page is rendered and isn't part of the DOM itself, so that isn't the problem.

The problem instead is that you're not directly targeting the element the price is contained within, instead you're targeting the `p` parent of that element which contains the text "100+ tickets".

Instead, you need to select the `.price-range` element:

```
$price=$con->find('div.event-availability p span.price-range',0)->innertext;
```

Comment: HI
James Donnelly  I have already tried this and it wont work.